# viewpanel not showing the latest data

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a button that does the following:
1) Delete the current information in the form.
2) Runs javascript to create new entries in the form.

The information is displayed in a viewpanel.  The problem is that the information that is displayed is incomplete and old.  I added an additional button that only does a partial refresh.  Once the first button is finished running, I click on the second panel and this second refresh displays the latest data.  I have been playing with putting variations of XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:WrapperPanel}", {}); in the oncomplete event of the first button - to no avail.

Here is the code:

```
<xp:button id="button34"
                                value="Check Teacher Information"
                                styleClass="BlueButtonSmall">
                                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                    submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler50">
                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var serverName:NotesDatabase = database.getServer();
var PosdbName = new Array(serverName,"Position.nsf");
var CamdbName = new Array(serverName,"Campus.nsf");
var currentDB:NotesDatabase=session.getCurrentDatabase(); 

//Delete old records
var i = 0;
var  crview = database.getView("ChangeReport");
var crvec:NotesViewEntryCollection = crview.getAllEntries();
var crentry:NotesViewEntry = crvec.getFirstEntry();
while (crentry != null) {
    crDoc = crentry.getDocument();
    crDoc.remove(true);
    crDoc.recycle(); 
    if (i > 100) {
        print("Possible Loop HRMainX - breaking");
        break;
    }
    i++
    var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = crvec.getNextEntry(crentry);
    crentry.recycle();
    crentry = tmpentry;

}
database.updateFTIndex(false);

var aview = database.getView("NISDTeacher");
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = aview.getAllEntries();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getFirstEntry();

var i = 0;
while (entry != null) {
    var Enumber:string = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("TeacherEnumber");
    var Firstname = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("TeacherFirst");
    var Lastname = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("TeacherLast");

    var Active = @DbLookup(PosdbName,"All",Enumber,"Posd_Active");
    var Status = @DbLookup(PosdbName,"All",Enumber,"Posd_Status");
    if (Active === "Y" || Status === "A") {

        var CurrCampusNum = @DbLookup(PosdbName,"ActiveID",Enumber,"Posd_Campus");
        var CurrCampusType = @DbLookup(CamdbName,"Campus",CurrCampusNum,"Cmp_Level");
        if (CurrCampusType === "SP" || CurrCampusType === "EL" || CurrCampusType === "MS" || CurrCampusType === "HS") {

            var CampusNum = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("CampusNum");
            var PositionCode = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("TeacherPCode");

            var CurrFirstname = @Trim(@ProperCase(@DbLookup(PosdbName,"ActiveID",Enumber,"Posd_FName")));
            var CurrLastname = @Trim(@ProperCase(@DbLookup(PosdbName,"ActiveID",Enumber,"Posd_lname")));
            var CurrPositionCode = @DbLookup(PosdbName,"ActiveID",Enumber,"Posd_Job_Code");

            if (CurrFirstname !== Firstname) {
                var reportDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
                var changeDoc = currentDB.createDocument();
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","ChangeReport");
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("DateReported",reportDate);
                var Change = Enumber + " " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + " has a new Firstname of " + CurrFirstname;
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Change",Change)
                changeDoc.save();
            }
            if (CurrLastname !== Lastname) {
                var reportDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
                var changeDoc = currentDB.createDocument();
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","ChangeReport");
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("DateReported",reportDate);
                var Change = Enumber + " " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + " has a new Lastname of " + CurrLastname;
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Change",Change)
                changeDoc.save();
            }
            if (CurrCampusNum !== CampusNum) {
                var reportDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
                var changeDoc = currentDB.createDocument();
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","ChangeReport");
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("DateReported",reportDate);
                var CampusName = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("CampusName");
                var CurrCampusName = @DbLookup(CamdbName,"Campus",CurrCampusNum,"Cmp_ShortName");
                var Change = Enumber + " " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + " was teaching at " + CampusName + " (" + CampusNum + ") " +
                "and is now teaching at " + CurrCampusName + " (" + CurrCampusNum + ")";
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Change",Change)
                changeDoc.save();
            }
            if (CurrPositionCode !== PositionCode) {
                var reportDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
                var changeDoc = currentDB.createDocument();
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","ChangeReport");
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("DateReported",reportDate);
                var PositionTitle = entry.getDocument().getItemValueString("TeacherPTitle");
                var CurrPositionTitle = @DbLookup(PosdbName,"ActiveID",Enumber,"Posd_Title");
                var Change = Enumber + " " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + " was teaching " + PositionTitle + " (" + PositionCode + ") " +
                "and is now teaching " + CurrPositionTitle + " (" + CurrPositionCode + ")";
                changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Change",Change)
                changeDoc.save();
            }

        } else {
            var reportDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
            var changeDoc = currentDB.createDocument();
            changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","ChangeReport");
            changeDoc.replaceItemValue("DateReported",reportDate);
            var Change = Enumber + " " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + " no longer works as a classroom teacher.";
            changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Change",Change);
            changeDoc.save();
        }

    } else {
        var reportDate = session.createDateTime(@Now());
        var changeDoc = currentDB.createDocument();
        changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Form","ChangeReport");
        changeDoc.replaceItemValue("DateReported",reportDate);
        var Change = Enumber + " " + Firstname + " " + Lastname + " no longer works at the district.";
        changeDoc.replaceItemValue("Change",Change)
        changeDoc.save();
    }
    var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = vec.getNextEntry(entry);
    entry.recycle();
    entry = tmpentry;
    if (i > 2000) {
        print("Possible Loop HRMainX - breaking");
        break;
   }
   i++
}
database.updateFTIndex(false);

//view.postScript("alert('Done checking teacher information.')");
viewScope.resultsCellVis = true;
//view.postScript("partialRefreshPost('#{id:WrapperPanel}')")



    }]]></xp:this.action>

                                    <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:WrapperPanel}", {});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
                                </xp:eventHandler>
                            </xp:button>
```

Thanks for any pointers.
---Lisa&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but it may be that it's caching the view content (effectively doing a `setAutoUpdate(false)` on the view). What may work is, instead of the `onComplete` event doing a partial refresh, adding a server-side call at the end of your SSJS to `context.reloadPage()`. That will recreate all the components again. Theoretically, I would expect that to dump it's cached version of the view and retrieve it from scratch. You should also be able to do this with a partial refresh rather than the complete refresh you currently have coded.

See this blog post I did explaining the differences between full refresh, `context.reloadPage`, `context.redirectToPage()` etc http://www.intec.co.uk/viewscope-full-refresh-reloadpage/.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a context.reloadPage() because of the loss of viewScope.  However, I went ahead and changed the variables I needed to sessionScope and added the context.reloadPage() to the SSJS.   Interestingly, the viewPanel still did not display the current information.  What does work is to use a view.postScript("alert('Done.')"); to alert the user when the process is complete.  The user then clicks on a button that sets a visibility variable to true and does a partial refresh.  Voila, the correct information is presented.

Comment: This is why I was thinking that it would help if I could do a partial refresh when the SSJS has completed running.  I don't like having to make the user use 2 buttons to get the results.

Comment: Also, my original button was doing a full refresh because the view.postScript("alert('Done.')") would not work otherwise.  Turns out without a full refresh, the context.reloadPage()  would cause a 
 JVM: Error while executing JavaScript action expression.
 com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
CLFAD0134E: Exception processing.  Maybe it is because I am using include pages.

Comment: Paul, I am checking your answer.  I went back to the button code today and started building up the actions very slowly.  2 things are true: 1. the page reload worked 2. the view.postscript does NOT work with a full refresh rather it works with the partial refresh.   I just had way too many things going on to debug properly.  Zen and the Art of Computer Programming.  Still wish I could get the oncomplete action to work.  Maybe when I learn more about client side javascript.